# Is it possible to build a fully functional LAN without any router, only with a switch?

Tags: switch, ip, switching, network-discovery, ip-link-local

I have used Link Local protocol several times but only to link two computers or a computer and another device to transfer files via FTP.

But does Link Local protocol work for multiple hosts. Let's say that I would like to build an office Network WITHOUT access to Internet at all. If I have approximately 30 Hosts would a router bring any benefit to it or it is the same if I use let's say 7 switches and let every computer get its IP address using Link Local.

From what I understand, using NAT every computer would be able to know on which port to send a frame directed towards a specific IP address.

If I install printers on the Network and File Storage Servers would the application protocols that normally discover servers on the network work the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers only route between LANs. You can have a fully functional LAN, including DHCP, without a router. You only need a router if you need to be able to communicate with other LANs.

When you refer to "Link Local," I think you are really meaning [APIPA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220874). This will actually determine if a host is trying to use an already used link-local address and change it.

Frames do not get "*directed towards a specific IP address*;" frames have MAC addresses which a switch will use to send a frame send to a specific switch port. You are confusing layer-2 frames and layer-3 packets. A LAN is a layer-2 concept.

Whether or not you have DHCP on a LAN, the LAN can function normally, and printers, etc. can be discovered the same way they would if DHCP was on the LAN, assuming the devices were assigned IP addresses in the LAN network.

Comment: Apipa is the Microsof equivalent for this protocol from what i read. Is the protocol called differently on Linux? Linux machines must have some sort of autoconfiguring in the absence of a DHCP Server I think. I did not find anything about APIPA on Linux. Do you know if it is called differently?            Is it Stateless Autoconfiguration? Is this the same thing? Or zeroconf?

Comment: End-device configurations are off-topic here. You could ask on one of the Linux forums or [su]. All I can give you is the network perspective.